# Security Role Issue in CRM 2011 for Workflow on Custom Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a custom entity in CRM 2011 which a user can create an instance of.

When that instance is created, a workflow is kicked off which emails a user asking them to approve the instance.

The user gets the email and goes to the form for the entity where they mark it as Approved.

The workflow at this point is waiting for the Approval decision to be made (which it now is) but something to do with the users security role is blocking the workflow from proceeding. The workflow remains in a "waiting" status for the Wait Until.

If I do the same steps again but as an admin, it works correctly.

What permissions does the approving user need in order to not break the workflow?

I gave them Create/Write/Read to the entity, and WriteActivity, ReadQueue but it's not working

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid all I can offer is suggestions here:

1. Is the workflow actually still waiting on the wait until? Or has it failed and is in a waiting state? See if there is an error in the in the section at the bottom of the system job.
2. Who is the workflow actually running as? - have a look at the system job - I believe it will be the permissions of that user which are important.
3. Consider the business units here as well as the actual permissions granted, e.g. is the record owned by someone in a different business unit from the workflow owner?
4. If there is a permission missing you might be able to see which one in the in the crm trace logs, have a look at the async log.
5. Try granting the user the following permissions: Execute Workflow Job, Read & Write on System Jobs, Read on Process (you can always take them away later, if you find they are not required)

Comment: Hi, the workflow is in waiting state so no error. I have launched the workflow as an admin user each time and so maybe the regular user is unable to interfere with a workflow created by the admin? All the same business unit, been looking at trace logs and given prvWriteActivity and prvReadQueue. Nothing else showing yet. Will try granting the permissions you suggest tomorrow first thing, thanks!

Comment: By the way, prvReadQueue is for the queues in crm, its not the workflow queues - those are systems jobs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547441.aspx helps to make it slightly (emphasis on slightly) clearer what permissions actually mean.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I have queues involved is because my workflow sends an email to a team, which is a queue with an email address which goes to several people. PrvReadQueue was missing for both my 2 new security roles according to the trace

Answer (score 1):

Did you confirm that workflow is published Organization-wide?  It doesn't sound like that should be causing the problem, but I have run into that before.

Comment: Hi, yeah the scope is Organization and it's been published

Comment: The workflow runs as the workflow Owner, not the approver.  Make sure the workflow Owner has the permissions needed to perform your steps.  Also, did you create the Security Role for the Approver from scratch?  Sometimes there are very pick little settings that can have unexpected results.  If you are sure it's the approver's security, then I would try the approval with a default Security Role like Salesperson and if that works, compare the Security Role options.